# VS2013 - Failed to build (New Forms Project)

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a problem with VS2013, in that it won't build any projects, new or existing.

I'm always met with the error:

> ... Please build the project and retry, or set the output path and assemblyname properties to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

My output window shows:

> 1>Project 'WindowsFormsApplication3' is not up to date. Missing output file 'c:\users\ ... \WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication3.exe'.
>
> 1>------ Build started: Project: WindowsFormsApplication3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I've searched around and pretty much everyone seems to think to solve this I should have "build" checked within my configuration manager - it is.

Also, that in the Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run - I should have "on Run when projects are out of date:" set to prompt or always build - it is. It's also set to any cpu (although even fails still when set to x86 etc).

And finally, that my output path is set correctly, which it is "bin\Debug".

I'm racking my brain over this one, and I'm stumped. This all started happening after a reboot of the PC, and there were no issues before that. New VB apps will build fine, it's just the windows forms / console projects ones thats giving me hell.

== Edit ==

Tried a repair on the installation, had no effect on it at all, neither has a reset all settings.

I can build from the command line however (msbuild) - a clean/build will build with no errors, however if you then modify the project and try and build from the application proper it'll error again, with an error like:

> Project 'WindowsFormsApplication3' is not up to date. Input file 'c:\users\ ... \WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication3.pdb'.

Comment: Could be an issue with write permissions. Are you able to create a file in your output folder from visual studio ?

Comment: It already has a few files in there, even for the new applications - just not all of them (including the .exe)

Comment: Try the command line to investigate your problem further. Is that VB or C# ?

Comment: C# - it'll place the config and 3 vhost files in the output folder, but thats it

Comment: I seem to remember something similar happening for me in VS2010, I moved the debug folder somewhere else (rather than just delete it) and tried again. VS created a new debug folder and built successfuly, that's not to say it will work for you though.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work - it recreated the folder with its 4 files inside once more, that was it - still error'd out

Comment: Damn, sorry, I have no clue then... Seems I was better off staying on 2010 though, there seem to be quite a few issues with 2013 from what I've read lately.

Comment: I'd suggest to repair the installation.

Comment: Just tried that, no joy - still have the exact same problem :/

Comment: Does [this](http://cschleiden.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/vs2013-build-fails-without-errors/) or [this](http://www.dirkstrauss.com/visual-studio-2013-2/visual-studio-2013-build-fails#.UxJnFmfN3hQ) help you at all?

Comment: No user file for the projects, so nothing to delete @PeteR

Comment: @Ben,  I have been encountering this error too, today.  Interestingly, my solution was building fine.  Then it stopped.  For the life of me I cannot figure out why.  At first three of the projects in my four-project solution were effected.  Then I checked the fourth project against source control.  No differences.  Nothing has changed in the project.  I deleted the project folder, got latest, built, there is the error.  This is a big WTF moment for me.  It has to be something wrong with the VS environment, or the local machine.  Project builds flawlessly on TFS build server.

Comment: My install is still the same, I've resigned to forever build via the command line until something is fixed for now.

Comment: @Ben Interestingly, I logged in this morning having shut down my Dev VM over the weekend.  Performing a Clean and then a Build resulted in success.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem. Turned out we had to run VS with elevated privileges - even though it looked like it was running as admin (even declared the fact in the title bar).

We were using Avecto Defendpoint to provide the elevation if that helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The project now builds when I run with elevated rights..  Damn Avecto..