# Visual studio Typescript project build fails without displaying any error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, npm, typescript, typescript1.5

I have `Visual Studio 2013` with update 5. I recently installed `Web Essentials`. When I try to create a new typescript project and try to run, it fails with the following message. Though the verbosity is set to diagnostic, I don't see any detailed error.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CTPortal, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Could this be due to `typescript 1.5` being installed by both `npm` and as well by microsoft update.?

Could some one provide an insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

***Courtesy :*** [VS2013 - Failed to build (New Forms Project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120721/vs2013-failed-to-build-new-forms-project/31827434#31827434)

Avecto Defendpoint was the problem. When I ran with elevated rights, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Build And Run -> configure verbosity for the build. Most probably you'll see more details about your problem in the output

[image]